# How to get readable command outputs from terminal

Tags: python, shell

I'm running into a problem whit this script and I don't know how to describe it.
Here is the code:

```py
import subprocess
while True:
    imp = input(">>> ")
    proc = subprocess.Popen(imp, shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE,)
    output = proc.communicate()[0]
    print(output)
```

If you write `ping 192.168.0.1` as input it will output a binary number I think but the `.decode("utf-8")` function doesn't work

Comment: Can you paste the exact output? I'm curious what qualifies as a "binary number" in this context.

Comment: ok, the output is:

Comment: b'\r\n192.168.0.1 pingel\x82se - 32 b\xa0jtnyi adattal:\r\nV\xa0lasz 192.168.0.1: b\xa0jt=32 id\x8b<10 ezredmp. TTL=64\r\nV\xa0lasz 192.168.0.1: b\xa0jt=32 id\x8b<10 ezredmp. TTL=64\r\nV\xa0lasz 192.168.0.1: b\xa0jt=32 id\x8b<10 ezredmp. TTL=64\r\nV\xa0lasz 192.168.0.1: b\xa0jt=32 id\x8b<10 ezredmp. TTL=64\r\n\r\n192.168.0.1 ping-statisztik\xa0ja:\r\n    Csomagok: k\x81ld\x94tt = 4, fogadott = 4, elveszett = 0\r\n                        (0% vesztes\x82g),\r\nOda-vissza \xa3t ideje k\x94zel\xa1t\x8blegesen, milliszekundumban:\r\n    minimum = 0ms, maximum = 0ms, \xa0tlag = 0ms\r\n'

Comment: sorry that it's in hungarian

Comment: you just need to `decode` the output, check my answer!

Comment: Oh, it's a `bytes` object with some \x escape sequences. I thought you were getting something like "01000110" :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use `decode` the output you get when you run a command, that is.
Note that since the OP is using hungarian, the encoding is `ISO-8859-2` and not `utf-8`

```
import subprocess
while True:
    imp = input(">>> ")
    proc = subprocess.Popen(imp, shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE,)
    output = proc.communicate()[0]
    #Decode the binary string 
    print(output.decode('ISO-8859-2'))
```

A sample output will be

```
>>> ping -c 1 127.0.0.1
PING 127.0.0.1 (127.0.0.1): 56 data bytes
64 bytes from 127.0.0.1: icmp_seq=0 ttl=64 time=0.045 ms

--- 127.0.0.1 ping statistics ---
1 packets transmitted, 1 packets received, 0.0% packet loss
round-trip min/avg/max/stddev = 0.045/0.045/0.045/0.000 ms

>>>
```

The new encoding works with the OP's example output

```
s = b'\r\n192.168.0.1 pingel\x82se - 32 b\xa0jtnyi adattal:\r\nV\xa0lasz 192.168.0.1: b\xa0jt=32 id\x8b<10 ezredmp. TTL=64\r\nV\xa0lasz 192.168.0.1: b\xa0jt=32 id\x8b<10 ezredmp. TTL=64\r\nV\xa0lasz 192.168.0.1: b\xa0jt=32 id\x8b<10 ezredmp. TTL=64\r\nV\xa0lasz 192.168.0.1: b\xa0jt=32 id\x8b<10 ezredmp. TTL=64\r\n\r\n192.168.0.1 ping-statisztik\xa0ja:\r\n Csomagok: k\x81ld\x94tt = 4, fogadott = 4, elveszett = 0\r\n (0% vesztes\x82g),\r\nOda-vissza \xa3t ideje k\x94zel\xa1t\x8blegesen, milliszekundumban:\r\n minimum = 0ms, maximum = 0ms, \xa0tlag = 0ms\r\n'
print(s.decode('ISO-8859-2'))
```

The output is

```
192.168.0.1 pingelse - 32 b jtnyi adattal:
V lasz 192.168.0.1: b jt=32 id<10 ezredmp. TTL=64
V lasz 192.168.0.1: b jt=32 id<10 ezredmp. TTL=64
V lasz 192.168.0.1: b jt=32 id<10 ezredmp. TTL=64
V lasz 192.168.0.1: b jt=32 id<10 ezredmp. TTL=64

192.168.0.1 ping-statisztik ja:
 Csomagok: kldtt = 4, fogadott = 4, elveszett = 0
 (0% vesztesg),
Oda-vissza Łt ideje kzelĄtlegesen, milliszekundumban:
 minimum = 0ms, maximum = 0ms,  tlag = 0ms
```

Comment: This seems like a sensible approach. But OP says "but the `.decode("utf-8")` function doesn't work". I'm curious why it would work for you and not him.

Comment: because OP's output is hungarian and not english, so `utf-8` won't work! Let me check how to decode a hungarian binary string

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/KEVIN/PycharmProjects/Terminal/test.py", line 7, in <module>
    print(output.decode('utf-8'))
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x82 in position 20: invalid start byte

Comment: Yes, I corrected the encoding, check my code update and try again! @TNTthelagger

Comment: @Kevin I updated the encoding to decode hungarian and it works :)

Comment: Which ones? I just did a google search and found this encoding, unfortunately I don't know Hungarian or which encoding is correct, and that is something you can find out yourself, and honestly it is a bit out of scope of question too!

Comment: But since the code works for you now and is able to decode something, could you please be kind enough to accept this answer :) @TNTthelagger

Comment: @ Devesh Kumar Singh the Hungarian characters don't work

Comment: Which ones? Sorry it will be a fool's errand for me to try to figure it out, I am sure if you look online, and try other encodings, some will work! I am sorry I cannot help you more :( @TNTthelagger

Comment: last thing what if I need English characters ??

Comment: then the encoding `utf-8` should work which I was using earlier :)